# Xelatex Crashes on item-bullets

Tags: xetex, itemize

I have installed a local version of the latest TeXLive distribution and xelatex 
crashes with the following error message, using the little document below.

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.3-0.9997.5 (TeX Live 2011)
restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
...
(./xelatex-test.aux)
Output file removed.
)
Error 256 (driver return code) generating output;
file xelatex-test.pdf may not be valid.
Transcript written on xelatex-test.log.
```

When putting in \item[] to avoid the bullet the file compiles. However  `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` did not bring the solution.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}

\usepackage{fontenc}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text} % To support LaTeX quoting style

%\usepackage{amssymb, amsthm}  %amsthm depends on amssymb
\usepackage{unicode-math}


\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
 \item test
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You should *not* load `xunicode` before `fontspec` (in your case `fontspec` is loaded by xltxtra). This will break the xunicode definitions and in your case it means that a different font is used for the bullets (lmsy10). Nevertheless xelatex shouldn't crash because of this. You could try to run `xelatex --output-driver="xdvipdfmx -vv" yourfile` on the command line. Perhaps the output will give more informations why your xetex doesn't like this font.

Comment: Tanks that helped!

Answer (score 3):

Update your TeX Live with tlmgr and try again. Your code works well on my PC.

BTW,

- Don't use `xltxtra`, it is obsolete.
- You don't need to use `xunicode` yourself.
- You don't need to use `fontenc` yourself, especially without any options.

My XeTeX version:

```
XeTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.3-0.9997.5 (Web2C 2011)
```

Packages (with `\listfiles` in the preamble):

```
  report.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size11.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
 fontenc.sty
xunicode.sty    2011/09/09 v0.981 provides access to latin accents and many oth
er characters in Unicode lower plane
graphicx.sty    1999/02/16 v1.0f Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
  keyval.sty    1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
graphics.sty    2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2010/04/23 v1.9 graphics configuration of TeX Live
   xetex.def    2009/11/22 v0.94 LaTeX color/graphics driver for XeTeX (RRM/JK)

 xltxtra.sty    2010/09/20 v0.5e Improvements for the "XeLaTeX" format
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
 ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
fontspec.sty    2011/09/18 v2.2a Advanced font selection for XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX
   expl3.sty    2011/10/09 v2900 L3 Experimental code bundle wrapper
 l3names.sty    2011/10/09 v2896 L3 Experimental namespace for primitives
l3bootstrap.sty    2011/09/10 v2798 L3 Experimental bootstrap code
    etex.sty    1998/03/26 v2.0 eTeX basic definition package (PEB)
    calc.sty    2007/08/22 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
   color.sty    2005/11/14 v1.0j Standard LaTeX Color (DPC)
   color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
l3basics.sty    2011/10/09 v2896 L3 Experimental basic definitions
 l3expan.sty    2011/10/09 v2896 L3 Experimental argument expansion
    l3tl.sty    2011/09/16 v2831 L3 Experimental token lists
   l3seq.sty    2011/10/09 v2896 L3 Experimental sequences and stacks
   l3int.sty    2011/10/09 v2896 L3 Experimental integers
 l3quark.sty    2011/10/09 v2896 L3 Experimental quarks
   l3prg.sty    2011/10/09 v2896 L3 Experimental control structures
 l3clist.sty    2011/10/09 v2896 L3 Experimental comma separated lists
 l3token.sty    2011/10/09 v2896 L3 Experimental token manipulation
  l3prop.sty    2011/09/17 v2839 L3 Experimental property lists
   l3msg.sty    2011/10/09 v2896 L3 Experimental messages
    l3io.sty    2011/10/09 v2896 L3 Experimental input-output operations
  l3file.sty    2011/10/09 v2896 L3 Experimental file operations
  l3skip.sty    2011/10/09 v2896 L3 Experimental dimensions and skips
  l3keys.sty    2011/09/10 v2800 L3 Experimental key-value interfaces
    l3fp.sty    2011/09/26 v2857 L3 Experimental floating-point operations
   l3box.sty    2011/10/09 v2896 L3 Experimental boxes
l3coffins.sty    2011/09/12 v2814 L3 Experimental coffin code layer
 l3color.sty    2011/09/07 v2776 L3 Experimental colour support
l3luatex.sty    2011/09/10 v2798 L3 Experimental LuaTeX-specific functions
  xparse.sty    2011/10/09 v2900 L3 Experimental document command parser
fontspec-patches.sty    2011/09/18 v2.2a Advanced font selection for XeLaTeX/Lu
aLaTeX
fixltx2e.sty    2006/09/13 v1.1m fixes to LaTeX
fontspec-xetex.sty    2011/09/18 v2.2a Advanced font selection for XeLaTeX/LuaL
aTeX
 fontenc.sty
  eu1enc.def    2010/05/27 v0.1h Experimental Unicode font encodings
  eu1lmr.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
fontspec.cfg
realscripts.sty    2010/09/30 v0.3 Access OpenType subscripts and superscripts
metalogo.sty    2010/05/29 v0.12 Extended TeX logo macros
unicode-math.sty    2011/09/19 v0.6a Unicode maths in XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
l3keys2e.sty    2011/10/09 v2900 LaTeX2e option processing using LaTeX3 keys
catchfile.sty    2011/03/01 v1.6 Catches the contents of a file (HO)
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/message (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/04/18 v1.20 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2011/02/16 v1.5 Prefix for e-TeX command names (HO)
  fix-cm.sty    2006/09/13 v1.1m fixes to LaTeX
  ts1enc.def    2001/06/05 v3.0e (jk/car/fm) Standard LaTeX file
filehook.sty    2011/10/12 v0.5d Hooks for input files
unicode-math-xetex.sty    
unicode-math-table.tex
   t3cmr.fd    2001/12/31 TIPA font definitions
  omslmr.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
 omslmsy.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
```

Comment: I gave my very best so far, but I cannot update. tlmgr is not installed (no file anywhere in the tex-tree); Looked at the website, no possibility to download tlmgr. I downloaded update-tlmgr-latest.sh instead and executed this which failed because kpsewhich --var-value=SELFAUTOPARENT returns / instead of my texlive directory. I have been searching for about half an hour now to find out where kpsewhich could possibly get this variable (probably from its own location, definitely not from environment variables and not from the texmf.cnf file). And there is no switch to set it. I'm stuck